# How do i move like 20% of an image move to the edge of my webpage, so as to make that 20% of the image no longer visible to the user

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, position

I have been trying to move an image to the edge of my webpage so that users can only see part of the image and not full. Imagine passing through a door and stopping half way. Half of your body can be seen, the other half can't be seen. I'm trying to achieve this with the computer in the image. The first monitor screen positioned to the left.

I have tried positioning, flex but still couldn't pull if out.

Comment: share the code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could position it absolutely to its parents and then use negative `left` or `right` to move it outside of the screen.
Or simply just position it relative to its original place.

Example:

```css
    div{
      background:lightblue;
      height:100vh;
      padding:20px;
      position:relative;
    }
    #img_1{
      width:200px;
      height:150px;
      position:absolute;
      left:-40px;
    }
#img_2{
      width:200px;
      height:150px;
      position:relative;
      left:-40px;
    }
```

```html
<p>this image is positioned absolute to it's parents:</p>
   <div>
    <img id='img_1'  src='https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/54e4dd424354a514f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e5074417d2e72d19e4fcc_640.jpg' alt='my image' />
   </div>
    
<p>this image is positioned relative to it's original position:</p>
<img id='img_2' src='https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/54e4dd424354a514f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e5074417d2e72d19e4fcc_640.jpg' alt='my image' />
```